# Фоновый поток Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Доброго времени суток !

Мне нужно раз в 5-10 сек получать информацию от сервера в приложении под Android8 и выше. Даже если приложение закрыто.

Не принципиально кто будет инициировать обмен, приложение или сервер, но предпочтительно чтоб приложение запрашивало данные.

Подскажите, с помощью чего это можно реализовать ?
Пробовал WorkManager, но он как-то не стабильно работает на моём Note 6 Pro, да и ограничение в 15мин меня не устраивает.

Эту задачу как-то реализуют мессенджеры, типа телеграма, вайбера и т.д. Так вот, а как они это делают ?

Ну и очень желательно без сторонних сервисов, которые сегодня работают а завтра по политическим причинам отказываются работать.

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение работает в гугловой экосистеме то использовать - Google cloud messaging.
Для хуавея есть свой аналог Huawei messaging service. Кажется у самсунга был свой аналог.

Во всех этих случаях используется сторонний сервер. Сделать свой аналог gcm можно, но не имеет смысла, тк решение будет работать сильно хуже, по батарее и другим ресурсам телефона. Как вариант можно попробовать поднять фореграунд сервис с нотификацией, и засыпать\просыпаться каждые 10 секунд, но большинство современных телефонов увидев такую активность предложат юзеру "оптимизировать" поведение приложения и все закончится.